# How to get or wait for the result code of an AT Command?

Tags: powerbuilder, at-command, mscomm32

How can I get or wait for the result code of an AT Command without using the `Sleep()` function in PowerBuilder? I am using the MSComm OLE Control for PowerBuilder. Could I do a While Loop unti the `MSCOmm.Input` property returns the proper buffer?(e.g, `OK`) However, I tried this but the `Input` returns an empty string.

Here is my PB Code:

```
String numbers[]

numbers[1] = "+639394854493"
numbers[2] = "+639394854491"
numbers[3] = "+639394854492"
numbers[4] = "+639394854493"
numbers[5] = "+639394854494"

int cnt = 1 
for cnt = 1 to 5
    Sleep(0.5)
    ole_1.object.Output = "AT" + Char(13) + Char(10)
    Sleep(0.5)
    ole_1.object.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" + Char(13) + Char(10)
    Sleep(0.5)
    ole_1.object.Output = "AT+CMGS=" + Char(34) + numbers[cnt] + Char(34) + Char(13) + Char(10)
    Sleep(0.5)
    ole_1.object.Output = sle_2.text + " - " + string(cnt) + Char(26)
next
```

And here is the port settings:

```
ole_1.object.CommPort = 7
ole_1.object.Settings = "115200,n,8,1"
ole_1.object.RThreshold = 1
ole_1.object.InputLen = 0
ole_1.object.InputMode = 0
ole_1.object.PortOpen = True
```

Any suggestions? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed instead of waiting for an amount of time, you could read some returned data from the `Input` property. The `ATxx` command set to communicate with modems is a far memory to me, but in most cases the modem returns an `OK` if the command succeded. Maybe that you have to tweak the input parameters

After some data was sent, wait until `OK` is returned to the serial line (idea adapted from the [official MSComm example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259394%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), untested):

```
ole_1.object.InputLen = 0 //Tell the control to read entire buffer when Input is used.
ole_1.object.Output = "AT+CMGF=1" + Char(13) + Char(10)
string ls_inp
Do
  Yield()
  ls_inp += ole_1.object.Input
Loop Until Right(ls_inp, 5) = " OK" + Char(13) + Char(10)
```

You would also need to adapt that code in cases where the `AT` command fails, I dunno how the error is returned to the serial line.

*Edit*: used the `Right()` func as suggested by OP in case where the commands are echoed in the modem answers

Comment: The loop won't stop. I tried to output `ls_inp` after it has been initialized in the loop and it returns blank.

Comment: I got it to work, but the `ls_inp` is now `AT+CMGF=1 OK` how do make the `ls_inp` to return only OK?

Comment: It seems that your modem is echoing the commands. Perhaps that sending an `ATE0` command to disable echo after the initial `AT` command can disable it. Another option is to replace the loop until test with `left(ls_inp,5) = ' OK + Char(13) + Char(10)`?

Comment: @JaymarkDacpano: glad to see that it helped you! How did you eventually fix your problem?

Comment: I used the `Right()` function instead, like so, `Right(ls_inp, 5)` so that it would just get the last line. Because the `Input` inputs the modems response per line.

Comment: @JaymarkDacpano: gosh! of course I meant `right()` instead of `left()` in my comment. (never do two things at once :oS)  I updated my answer to reflect your used solution for any newcomer. Thanks for your feedback.